# How to set a process.env variable in command and retreive in webpack file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, process

Following is the command -

```
"analyze": "node scripts/analyze.js"
```

In which I am trying to set a `process.env` variable like -

```
"analyze": "node scripts/analyze.js BUNDLE_ANALYZE=true"
```

In my `webpack.config.js` file, I am writing a condition like -

```
if(process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE) {
  // DO a Bundle analyzer push to the main plugin array
}
```

But its not working, let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable declaration should be before node:

```
"analyze": "BUNDLE_ANALYZE=true node scripts/analyze.js"
```

Keep in mind that "true" will come as a string.

You can also use a flag:

```
node scripts/analyze.js --analyse
```

And then in your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  process.argv.includes('--analyse')
    ? new (require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')).BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    : null,
].filter(Boolean),
```

Comment: I think it should be `process.argv.includes('analyse')` instead of `process.argv.includes('--analyse')`..correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If your start your script with `node scripts/analyze.js --analyse`, this `process.argv.includes('--analyse')` works but sadly this `process.argv.includes('analyse')` won't. If you don't want `--` you could do something like this `!!process.argv.find(x => /analyse/.test(x))`